# Why doesn't SimpleCov recognize my module tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, simplecov

I have a module in app/helpers that I've written tests for in test/helpers, but after running SimpleCov, it's showing 0% coverage for my helper.

I'm using MiniTest to run my tests and SimpleCov looks to be accurately reporting the test coverage for my other files.
For my module, I have:

```
module MyHelper
  def some_method
    ...
  end
end
```

For my test file, I have:

```
class MyHelperTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  describe 'when extending a class' do
    it 'should work' do
      assert some_method
    end
  end
end
```

Any idea why SimpleCov might not be recognizing my tests?

Comment: Does it work if you actually use `ActionView::TestCase` instead of `ActiveSupport::TestCase`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `config.cache_classes = false` in `environments/test.rb` fixed my reporting issue.